# can not visit the web app made of angular cli on the digitalocean

Tags: firewall, digital-ocean, angular-cli

I have built a simple web app using angular-cli 2,it works well in the local machine. now i tried to deploy it onto a digitalocean server,[image]

however when going to the web server link with http://ip address:4200, i can't visit the web app.

Note: I can make sure the firewall is open to the web application on that port since in `ufw status` shows `4200 ALLOW Anywhere`

Answer (score 2):

You need to serve the actual ip address of the server, by default `ng serve` will use the loopback address. You can achieve this with:

`ng serve --host 0.0.0.0`